# Django request.post no data available

Tags: python, django

I have already searched for similar questions on StackOverflow but could not find the solution that would work for me. I have the following code snippet:

```
def post_request(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token = request.POST.get("access_token"), expires__gt = timezone.now())
```

When I make the HTTP request to this function, I get the following error: `AccessToken matching query does not exist.` , I started debugging the app.

**The problem** is in `request.POST.get("access_token")`

request.POST = `<QueryDict: {}>` . I have no data in there

I am making a **POST** request in POSTMAN, where I added the data to body -> form-data. I also tried sending data through body->raw->json but anyway the request.POST does not contain anything.

[image]

What is the cause that I have no Post data?
How can I get the POST data?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post your template code here ?

Comment: what do you mean by template code?

Comment: view template from which the post request is coming

Comment: I am using postman. I will upload now the screenshot

Comment: can you please try this request.POST.get("access_token", "") and just try to print it

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I have moved the data from `form-data` to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and now I can access the `request.POST.get("key")` . @Alasdair move please your comm to the answer so that I can mark it as accepted. Can you also explain what is the diff between `form-data` and `x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: Check `request.body` for different content types, and check what your `header` is set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `form data`. `x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default form encoding for HTML forms.

Django does support `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, which can be used for [uploading files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads). So I'm afraid I can't explain why your request from Postman didn't work when you selected `form data`. Perhaps your request had an incorrect header.

Comment: it is very strange but yesterday it worked, but today I can not see again anything in the request.POST

Comment: it does not matter how I send the request (form-data or x-www-form-url-encoded)

Comment: the problem seems to be the way I run the project. When I run the project using the configuration of Visual Studio Code, I get always null post. When the project is ran through terminal it works. Very strange